# PWA and local file system

Tags: web-applications, progressive-web-apps

can progressive web application store some text file in a custom folder on disk (ex, not the configured downloads folder). I need to save some small text file (ex with name 00123.ddd) in a custom folder, and this folder should not ne used for any other purposes, but to keep the file that I need to save.

Or this is only possible with desktop apps?